# C# embed resource in .Js file rather then .cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have MVC application. Lot of logic reside in javascript.

I want to  embed C# code into the view.  For example

```
 @Url.Action("Dosomething", "something")

                   Or

 @MyNamespace.SomeVar
```

Everything worked as expected till I have the code in view (.cshtml) file only. But as logic increased. I moved the javaScript into another file (.js). The whole code broke.

### Is there any solution or workaround for the same?

ok, so i will be getting value in my view file then using it in javascript.

I, however have a follow up question...

How can i access enum value in view.

i am doing something like this:

```
 var valjs = '@MyEnum.VAL1'
```

This caused the name to be copied in javascript like this:

```
var valjs = 'VAL1'
```

but i wanted corresponding enum value:

```
var valjs = "1";
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you include js file in the view ?

Comment: Razor code is parsed for the view only and external files are ignored. You would need to set variables in the main view so that they could be accessed from the external file or make use of `data` attributes in elements and them access using `var myVar = $(myElement).data(..);`

Comment: the solution to my second question was to use enum syntax something like this var valjs = '@( (Int32)MyEnum.VAL1)'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that razor code is server side and it will  only work in View, when you moved your js code in seperate js file, the razor code will not work there as it is server side code, you have to use html5 data-attribute for accessing razor values there.

### For Example:

In View you were doing this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Dosomething", "something")';
```

this will work fine in view but in seperate js file it will not work as `@Url.Action("Dosomething", "something")` is server side you can do something like this:

```
<div id="url" data-url="@Url.Action("Dosomething", "something")">
</div>
```

and in js file:

```
 var url = $("#url").data("url");
```